# How to add x-axis labels to time series plots?

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

I have created a `ts` object for my data as below:

```
sensor_test<-ts(Newdf_sorted$total_consumption,start = c(2018,04),end=c(2019,09),
                frequency = 12)
output:
  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2018              59  65  70  83  62  98  63  95  57
2019  57  69  75  80  67  85  79  82 110
```

However, when I plot the same, the plot is generated by shifting it before 2 months:

```
plot(sensor_test)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've to work a bit with your data, then you can plot them:

```
# random data, due you've not post any sample data
set.seed(1234)
sensor_test<-ts(round(rnorm(18,1,2),1),start = c(2018,04),end=c(2019,09),frequency = 12)

library(zoo)
# convert as data.frame and taking care of the dates
sensor_test_df <- data.frame(sensor_test = as.vector(sensor_test),
                             time = format(as.yearmon(time(sensor_test)),"%Y %m"))
```

Now you can plot it:

```
# the plot, you've to specify the type
plot(sensor_test_df$sensor_test, type = 'l', xaxt = "n")
# the axis labels
axis(1, at=1:18, labels=sensor_test_df$time)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this works. I would like to understand that why after creating a ts object, it does not plot in order of the parameters mentioned, like start(2018,04), so it's pretty clear that the plot should ideally start from April month instead of Feb.

Comment: You're welcome! I **suppose** because `plot()` takes the dates as numeric and use them only to have the order of plotting, but you've to specify the labels. Maybe a more experienced user can add some stronger clarifications, I'd read them gladly.